# Convert Excel Formula to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this formula that looks at various criteria across multiple columns and checks to see that if all the all the criteria match, it will paste data from one column to another.  I've tried a couple ways to get it into VBA, but I can't seem to get anything to work.  Thanks!

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$1112,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$1112=$U$7)*($C$2:$C$1112=$W$7)*($B$2:$B$1112=F3),0))
```

Comment: What did you try, and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 changes:

(1) To use a function in VBA when it is available in native Excel, you need to preface each function with Application.WorksheetFunction. ie:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(y,z)
```

(2) To reference a cell within a sheet, in VBA, you need to access it specifically, in one of a few ways. The simplest for our purposes is the RANGE property, as follows:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:A2"))
```

So to put those two changes together, your formula would look like this:

```
=Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(Range("$D$2:$D$1112",Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH(1,(RANGE("$A$2:$A$1112"=RANGE("$U$7")*(Range("$C$2:$C$1112"=Range("$W$7")*(Range("$B$2:$B$1112"=Range("F3"),0))
```

Although I see now having gone through this that you seem to be using an Array Formula - not sure if any special jigging is required to get that to work.

Answer (score 3):

You are not going to be able to use that array formula to directly return a value to a cell. VBA does not process an array formula the way that the worksheet can. The best method is to use the worksheet's processing or one of the [Application Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) methods.

Your lack of a worksheet to reference troubles me. When a formula is in a worksheet cell, it *knows* what worksheet it is on. When using formulas within VBA, the parent worksheet is a 'best guess' without explicit worksheet referencing.

Here are three methods to put the results from that array formula into Z2:Z4 on the active worksheet. Remember that these cell references should be modified to include the worksheet name.

```
With ActiveSheet
    'this simply puts the formula into the worksheet then reverts the cell from the formula to the returned formula value
    .Range("Z2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($D$2:$D$1112, MATCH(1, ($A$2:$A$1112=$U$7)*($C$2:$C$1112=$W$7)*($B$2:$B$1112=F3), 0))"
    .Range("Z2") = .Range("Z2").Value

    'this uses the 'square bracket' method of evaluating a formula on-the-fly
    'the formula being evaluated can be array or non-array
    'this method is does not like building a formula string from pieces of text
    .Range("Z3") = [INDEX($D$2:$D$1112, MATCH(1, ($A$2:$A$1112=$U$7)*($C$2:$C$1112=$W$7)*($B$2:$B$1112=F3), 0))]

    'similar to the method directly above, Application.Evaluate does just that.
    'the formula being evaluated can be array or non-array
    'this method is easier to build a formula string from pieces of text
    .Range("Z4") = Application.Evaluate("INDEX($D$2:$D$1112, MATCH(1, ($A$2:$A$1112=$U$7)*($C$2:$C$1112=$W$7)*($B$2:$B$1112=F3), 0))")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that has definitely gotten the ball rolling a bunch, but is there a way to loop down an empty column and insert that formula into each cell in that empty column?

Comment: No need to loop. The [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) can put it into every blank cell but you don't want to overextend it. There is not enough information (worksheet name, extents of data, etc) to provide an example.

Comment: Here's a link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318280/convert-formula-to-vba  This has all the code so you can get a better idea of what I'm doing.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Now that it seems you've abandoned this question and moved on, perhaps you should take a moment to review [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)