# Convert Formula to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Through the help of the community here, I have constructed this piece of code where I sort through data based on certain criteria.  My problem comes in the FormulaArray section, I have kind of a pseudo coded version of what I want the code to do now, but I'm not quite sure how to make it work 100%  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Sub BringData()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb3 As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\book1-2.xlsm")
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 wb1.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\book1-2copy.xlsm")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\book2.xlsm")
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook

Dim parameter1 As String
Dim condition1 As String
Dim parameter2 As String
Dim condition2 As String
Dim value As String

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
Dim destination1 As Worksheet
Dim destination2 As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn1 As Long
Dim lastFullColumn1 As Long

Set destination1 = ws1
lastFullColumn1 = destination1.Cells(1,      destination1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If lastFullColumn1 > 1 Then
emptyColumn1 = lastFullColumn1 + 1
End If

Dim startrow As Range
Dim stoprow As Range
Dim l As Long

With wb3.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set startrow = .Columns("E").Find(What:="START", LookIn:=xlValues,    lookat:=xlWhole)
Set stoprow = .Columns("E").Find(What:="STOP", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

End With

   For l = startrow.Row + 1 To stoprow.Row - 1

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   With wb3.Sheets("Sheet1")

   parameter1 = .Cells(l, 6)
   condition1 = .Cells(l, 7)
   parameter2 = .Cells(l, 8)
   condition2 = .Cells(l, 9)
   value = .Cells(l, 10)

    End With

    With wb1.Sheets(1).Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(1, lastFullColumn1))


            Dim parameter1column As Range
            Set parameter1column = .Find(What:=wb3.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(l, 6).value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            Dim parameter1columnLetter As String
            parameter1columnLetter = ColumnLetter(parameter1column.Column)

            Dim parameter2column As Range
            Set parameter2column = .Find(What:=wb3.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(l, 8).value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            Dim parameter2columnLetter As String
            parameter2columnLetter = ColumnLetter(parameter2column.Column)

            Dim valuecolumn As Range
            Set valuecolumn = .Find(What:=wb3.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(l, 10).value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            Dim valuecolumnLetter As String
           valuecolumnLetter = ColumnLetter(valuecolumn.Column)




            Dim lastFullcolumn2letter As String
            Dim lastFullColumn2 As Long
            Dim emptyColumn2 As Long
            Dim emptycolumn2letter As String

            Set destination2 = ws2
                lastFullColumn2 = destination2.Cells(1, destination2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If lastFullColumn2 > 1 Then
                emptyColumn2 = lastFullColumn2 + 1
            End If

            lastFullcolumn2letter = ColumnLetter(lastFullColumn2)
            emptycolumn2letter = ColumnLetter(emptyColumn2)



            Dim patid1 As Range
            Dim patid2 As Range

            Set patid1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D:D")
            Set patid2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("D:D")

            Dim parameter1columnvalue As Range
            Set parameter1columnvalue =   Columns(parameter1column.Column).Cells

             Dim parameter2ColumnValue As Range
             Set parameter2ColumnValue = Columns(parameter2column.Column).Cells

            Dim valuecolumnValue As Range
            Set valuecolumnValue = Columns(valuecolumn.Column).Cells




            Dim i As Long
            Dim k As Long
            Dim m As Long
           Dim Lookupstring As String

            With ws2

            .Range("emptycolumn2letter").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(ws1! valuecolumnletter:valuecolumnletter, MATCH(1, (ws1! parameter1columvalue= wb3.Sheets(1) condition1.value)*(ws1! parameter2columnvalue = wb3.Sheets(1) condition1.value)*(patid1=patid2), 0))"
            .Range("emptycolumn2letter") =  .Range("emptycolumn2letter").value


            End With

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next l

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox " This code ran in " & SecondsElapsed & "seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

The area I'm having trouble with is this:

```
With ws2
    .Range("emptycolumn2letter").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(ws1! valuecolumnletter:valuecolumnletter, MATCH(1, (ws1! parameter1columvalue= wb3.Sheets(1) condition1.value)*(ws1! parameter2columnvalue = wb3.Sheets(1) condition1.value)*(patid1=patid2), 0))"
    .Range("emptycolumn2letter") =  .Range("emptycolumn2letter").value    
 End With
```

- Edit

  ```
  Dim lastFullRow1 As Long
  lastFullRow1 = destination1.Cells(destination1.Rows.Count,  1).End(xlUp).Row
  If lastFullRow1 > 1 Then
  emptyrow1 = lastFullRow1 + 1
  End If

  Set destination2 = ws2
  Dim lastFullRow2 As Long
  lastFullRow2 = destination2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  If lastFullRow2 > 1 Then
  emptyrow2 = lastFullRow2 + 1
  End If

      Dim pasterange As String
      Dim patid As String
      Dim condition1s As String
      Dim condition2s As String
      Dim values As String

      pasterange =  "lastfullcolumn2letter2:lastfullcolumn2letterlastfullrow2"
      patid = "D:D"
      condition1s = "parameter1columnletter1:parameter1columnletterlastfullrow1"
      condition2s = "parameter2columnletter1:parameter2columnletterlastfullrow1"
      values = "valuecolumnletter:valuecolumnletterlastfullrow1"

      MsgBox "column row " & condition1s

      With ws2

      .Range(pasterange).FormulaArray = _
          "=INDEX('" & ws2.Name & " '!' " & patid & ", " & _
          "MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!" & condition1s & "=" & condition1 & ")*" & _
                  "('" & ws1.Name & "'!" & condition2s & "=" & condition2 & ")*" & _
                  "('" & ws1.Name & "'!" & values & "=" & value & "),0))"
          .Range(pasterange) = .Range(pasterange).value

      End With
  ```

Comment: Please limit the code shown to the smallest portion required to recreate the error; that's a lot of code to go through.

Comment: Is ws1 the actual name of the `Worksheet` or what you defined the `Variable` to be?

Comment: I Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)

Comment: I am sure you will get an exact fix, but the problem is that all variables need to be outside the quotes with and ampersand between.  Then call any range just as you would in normal vba.

Comment: Your problem is that you try to put a Formula into the workbook but refer to several variables and values inside the Formula `String` instead of outside the `String`

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand, but I think you find a value (or array) in your first `.Range("emptycolumn2letter)`, then you try to put this value into `.Range("emptycolumn2letter")`.
And I think `emptycolumn2letter` is only a letter (I don't know if your previous statement `ColumnLetter` works tofind the column letter).

But one observable problem is that `emptycolumn2letter` is only a letter, and you try to put a value to a column without row. It might be one of the error sources. Think like working on an Excel-sheet. You must give a starting cell point to be able to copy a value.

Comment: I tried to rework your code, but then I got to the second part of your MATCH formula.  It is supposed to be a range and you have a formula with multiple '=' signs.  Look at that part, it is not possible for anyone to guess well enough to fix.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mashup between using a formula as a VBA [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) and writing a formula in a worksheet cell.

Your use of `emptycolumn2letter` has a couple of issues. As mentioned by  user3714330 in comments, it doesn't appear to be a complete cell reference; just the column letter. `.Range("C2")` or `.Range("C:C")` is valid. `.Range("C")` is not. Additionally, once `emptycolumn2letter` has a valid cell address, you do not quote it; e.g. `.Range(emptycolumn2letter)` not `.Range("emptycolumn2letter")`. You would only use the latter is `emptycolumn2letter` was a named rage on the worksheet. It is not; it is a variable within the VBA procedure.

Similarly, `ws1` cannot be used unless the name of the worksheet was literally `ws1` which it does not appear to be. You need to break hte formula string up and use `ws1.name` concatenated inside the formula string.

On a related note, it is always good practise to use single quotes wrapped around worksheet names when constructing formulas from strings. If the worksheet name contains no spaces they are not needed but do no harm if included. If they are needed and not there, the formula breaks.

```
dim ec2L as string, p1cv as string, p2cv as string, p3cv as string, vcl as string
ec2L = "Z3"
vcl = "$D$2:$D$1112"
p1cv = "$A$2:$A$1112"
p2cv = "$C$2:$C$1112"
p3cv = "$B$2:$B$1112"
With ws2
    'formula to duplicate:
    '[INDEX($D$2:$D$1112, MATCH(1, ($A$2:$A$1112=$U$7)*($C$2:$C$1112=$W$7)*($B$2:$B$1112=F3), 0))]
    .Range(ec2L).FormulaArray = _
      "=INDEX('" & ws1.name & "'!" & vcl & ", " & _
        "MATCH(1, ('" & ws1.name & "'!" & p1cv & "=" & condition1 & ")*" & _
                 "('" & ws1.name & "'!" & p2cv & "=" & condition2 & ")*" & _
                 "('" & ws1.name & "'!" & p3cv & "=" & condition3 & "), 0))
    .Range(ec2L) =  .Range(ec2L).value    
End With
```

That is not completely 'turn-key' correct as there were a number of faluts above this code in your sub procedure but it should give you an idea of what to strive towards. Note that condition1, condition2  and condition3 are being treated as numbers. If they are text then they need to be wrapped in quotes as well.

You might find that using a cell's [Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) with `external:=true` is a more convenient method of getting the worksheet names and cell addresses into the formula in one piece.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I'm still a tad confused on how to name the worksheets so the computer will pick up the right values.  I'm also not too sure about the emptycolumn2letter value.  The value it returns is just the letter of the column, but can I not refer to a range as .Range("emptycolumn2letter:emptycolumn2letter")

Comment: No. As mentioned above, `.Range("A")` is not valid. `.Range("A:A")`, `.Range("A2:A99")` or `.Range("A2")` are valid. You do NOT want full column references in that array formula or be prepared to wait a LONG time for the calculation cycle to complete.

Comment: In the edits above I took a crack trying to go more along the lines of what you were saying.  I'm still not sure how the string values work though, I don't want the ranges to be defined by column letters, the ranges need to be defined by strings which represent column letters as found earlier in the code.  I hope I'm making some progress, Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Another comment about the naming of the sheets, am I supposed to just put ws1.name?  I tried writing ws1.USA (USA is  the name on the little tab at the bottom of the sheet) but that gave me a compile error: method or data member not found.

Comment: `ws1.name` returns `"USA"`. See Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx).

Comment: Ok great, I'm still stuck on those strings though.  For the strings I have defined in the edit, they just return the string of characters that I have in quotes.  For example, I want condition1s to return the range between column: parameter2columnletter, row: 1, and column parameter2columnletter, row: lastfullrow1.  I just get a mismatch error if I try setting as a range though